# PHP how to count only single click

Tags: php, click, counter

If I click mare that 1 time on banner my PHP function counting it, maybe are some solution to count only 1 click, or create faster redirection that user not have time to click more that 1 time ?

This is my function:

```
function wp125_adclick() {
    if (isset($_GET['adclick']) && $_GET['adclick'] != "" && ctype_digit($_GET['adclick'])) {
    $theid = $_GET['adclick'];
    global $wpdb;
    $adtable_name = $wpdb->prefix . "wp125_ads";
    $thead = $wpdb->get_row($wpdb->prepare(
        "SELECT target FROM {$adtable_name} WHERE id = %d",
        $theid
    ));
    $theid = $wpdb->escape($theid);
    $update = "UPDATE ". $adtable_name ." SET clicks=clicks+1 WHERE id='$theid'";
    $results = $wpdb->query( $update );
    header("Location: $thead->target");
    exit;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a session variable to count the clicks. So you can avoid to count multiple clicks.

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['click_already_saved'])) {
    $update = "UPDATE ". $adtable_name ." SET clicks=clicks+1 WHERE id='$theid'";
    $results = $wpdb->query( $update );
    $_SESSION['click_already_saved']=true;
}
```

Comment: If I guess correctly you use wordpress. WordPress will do that for you.